# How to add new class and autoload in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am new on Zend framework and using first time it. I am looking for simple basic tutorials which I can read in very short time. I also stuck on if I want to add new class in Zend library. And it should also auto load when I make any new controller.

Please give your opinions if you have.

Regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This helped me At the beginning:

http://www.zendcasts.com/

http://devzone.zend.com/search/results?q=autoload (just search)

As autoload your class, This is the my way:

Create folder 'My' into  library/
 in it create folder 'Utils' and in Utils file 'Utils.php' so the path is library/My/Utils/Utils.php

For this path You must call class: class My_Utils_Utils{ ... }

and in configs/application.ini  Put

appnamespace = "Application"

autoloaderNamespaces.my = "My_"

Then you can use namespace My_  and class  My_Utils_Utils

In controller: $test = new My_Utils_Utils();

Answer (score 0):

- I am looking for simple basic tutorials

  Here are a few tutorials I found while googling:

  1. [Official quickstart tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.html)
  2. A great book by frequent ZF-contributer Padráic Brady: [Survive the deep end!](http://survivethedeepend.com/)
  3. http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/
  4. Page with different tutorials: [ZFTutorials.com](http://www.zftutorials.com/)
- I also stuck on if I want to add new class in Zend library

  You should not add new classes to the library per se, but instead create your own library or add classes in the "models"-folder/folders (if you use the modular project layout). Autoloading is achieved by utilizing `Zend_Loader_Autoloader` and its subclasses. As long as you follow the PEAR convention, i.e. if you have a class `MyLib_Database_Table`, then it should be inside the folder `MyLib/Database`, and the filename should be `Table.php`. (also make sure that the parent folder of MyLib is on the project include path.

  To autoload simply use `new MyLib_Database_Table`, and the autoloader will load the class behind the scenes if necessary. Since 1.10 (I think), the autoloader also fully support PHP 5.3 namespaces. I.e:

  ```
  // Filepath: lib\MyLib\Database\Table.php

  namespace MyLib\Database;
  class Table {
  }
  ```

  will work with the same folder structure. Code example:

  ```
  use MyLib\Database\Table;
  class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
  {
     public function indexAction ()
     {
        $myTable = new Table();
     }
  }
  ```
- auto load when I make any new controller

  I'm not quite sure what you mean here. ZF does not have any dependency injection setup per default. But you can instantiate your classes without requiring them first if that's what you mean.