# Zend Framework calling another Controller Action

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi i have issue here of calling another controller action to send an mail, here is my code:

user.php

```
public function followAction()
{
     $follow_id = $this->_getParam('id');
     $response = "<a href='javascript: void(0)'  class='i-wrap ig-wrap-user_social i-follow_small-user_social-wrap'><i class='i i-follow_small-user_social ig-user_social'></i>Stop Following</a>";

     notifyEmail()  ------> need to call Notity Controller with notifyEmail() Action along with           
                       params
     $this->_helper->json($response);  ----> return json response
}
```

NotifyController.php

```
<?php

class NotifyController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */

    }

     public function index()
    {

    }

     public function notifyEmailAction()
    {
          // rest of email code goes here
    }

}
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You can write an action helper and put the email sending code in there. [Zend Action Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to move send mails functionality to another place, 
and call it in both methods.

Check this thread
[Calling member function of other controller in zend framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886291/calling-member-function-of-other-controller-in-zend-framework)

I suggest to create at the path /library a new folder 'My' and in it new file Utilities.php and in that file a new class where you can put all your help methods

```
class My_Utilities {
    // put here your custom help methods
}
```

You need to [auto-load that namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611578/how-to-add-new-class-and-autoload-in-zend-framework/7611955#7611955).In configs/application.ini put

```
autoloaderNamespaces.my = "My_"
```

Then you can use namespace My_ and class My_Utilities.

---

In any case, you can call method form another controller:

```
include 'NotifyController.php';
$a = new NotifyController($this->_request, $this->_response);
$a->notifyEmailAction();
```

Comment: Or instead of a global utilities class, a service object.

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->action('action', 'controller', 'module', 'params')
```

That view helper walk through frontController and dispatch all plugins again.

I think is not the best solution keep in mind wasting resources

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code
`$this->action("action","controller","module")`