# Call function in indexController from another controller Zend

Tags: function, zend-framework, controller, call

Need to call some function from another controller (not IndexController), for example:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

public function indexAction()
{
    $someFunction = new CustomController();
    $someFunction->someFunc();
}
```

}
But this throws an error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'CustomController' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\demo.ru\application\controllers\IndexController.php on line 13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `YourController::memberFunction()` does something that is needed across multiple controllers, put that code in a **action helper** or **library class**,

so that both controllers can access the shared functionality without having to depend on each other.

I would suggest you to follow DRY and move those functions to common library place.

to use with Namespace see

[Zend Framework calling another Controller Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391413/zend-framework-calling-another-controller-action)

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @user2794741,glad to help you,.