# How to call an action from an other controller - ZendFramework1

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I want to use an action call "loginAction" from a controller call "GestIdentController" inside a module call "default" in an other action call "suiviprodAction" in a controller call "AdminController" inside a module call "Supervision".

Can someone send me documentations about it, im a bit lost..

folder :

[image]

What am i tried to do in the controller AdminController :

```
    public function suiviprodAction(){
    $this->loginAction('ferran','ferran');
    // Connexion au fichier de label
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391413/zend-framework-calling-another-controller-action)

Be aware that if you use

```
$this->action('action', 'controller', 'module', 'params')
```

ZF1 will do the dispatch process again, this means that all the plugin and resources will be initialized again.

My advice is to implement a Dependency Injection Container like [zend-servicemanager](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-servicemanager) or [phpDI](http://php-di.org/), create your login service and use it wherever you need it.