# Zend Framework 1.x - How do I get data from database?

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, autoloader

**Here is my project structure: http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/7047/68818300.png**

I connected to database by using php.ini:

```
[production]
phpSetting.display_status_errors = 1
phpSetting.display_errors = 1

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "front"

resources.frontController.baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/zendfirst/"

resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "estore"

autoloadernamespaces.extendlib = "ExtendLib_"

resources.layout.layout = "index"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/templates/front/default"

[developer : production]
phpSetting.display_status_errors = 0
phpSetting.display_errors = 0
```

I searched on google but there were many ways to do but I don't know how. I'm trying this way but it doesn't work. Here is my model:

```
<?php

    class Model_User {
        protected $db;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->db = Zend_Registry::get('db');
        }

        public function listAll() {
            $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM SanPham ORDER BY Id DESC");
            return $sql->fetchAll();
        }
    }
```

And this is my controller:

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $muser = new Model_User();//error here
        $data = $muser->listAll();
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($data);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    public function viewAction() {

    }

    public function preDispatch() {

    }

}
```

The controller doesn't know what is user model. How should I call model in controller?
Here is my project: https://www.box.com/s/idw5twyyo41yn8gq1kfe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in your Bootstrap.php

```
protected function _initAutoLoad(){
    $resource_loader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
        array(
            'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace' => '',
            'resourceTypes' => array(
               'model' => array(
                    'path'      => 'models/',
                    'namespace' => 'Model_'
               ),
               ),
        )
    );
    return $resource_loader;
}
```

Or put in your ini file:

```
appnamespace = "Application"
```

than name your model

```
class Application_Model_User{ ... }
```

Comment: But I have three mmodules, it still doesn't know user model. I have just updated my project above.

Comment: I done as you said but it didn't work. Please see my project.

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/7611955/949273  http://stackoverflow.com/a/8232931/949273

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the autoloader doesn't know where Model_Users is.

You will need to config in a [resource autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html).

If for some reason this is library code (ie under Model directory right off of one of your include paths) then just add  `autoloadernamespaces.models = "Model_"` to your ini file

Comment: But I have three mmodules, it still doesn't know user model.